# Effects of increasing cache size on coherence miss

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Is coherence miss affected by cache size. (Does the increasing cache block size have effect on coherence miss?). Explain it

Can anyone help me on this question. I know the definition for the coherence miss but I dont know how the concept applies when we increase the cache size.

Comment: Are you asking about changing the *block* size (aka line size), or the total size of the cache (number of lines)?  Those would have very different effects.  Increasing block size makes false sharing more likely, but OTOH can pull more related data that you may access soon if one item of shared data spans multiple cache lines.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am asking about the total size of the cache. Can you explain the concept again with this concept because I don't really understand it.

Comment: IDK if there is a direct effect.  Maybe some lines that would have been evicted stay hot, so maybe some misses that would be capacity misses instead become coherency misses, if the access is from another core.  Obviously depends a *lot* on the workload.